# Add a Invoice for a customer using PHP API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I need to create an INVOICE for a customer. 
Invoice for existing customer and if not existed customer need to create for new customer.

I have been through this process,

[url]http://localhost/palmer_sdk/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/example_invoice_add.php[/url]

I'm stuck at this Error:

```
2500: [Invalid Reference Id, Invalid Reference Id : Line.SalesItemLineDetail.ItemRef]
```

Please can anyone help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the QuickBooks GUI, every line on a QuickBooks invoice links back to an ITEM/product/service type.

It looks like QuickBooks Online is telling you that the item you're referring to:

```
<ItemRef>8</ItemRef>
```

Does not exist.

Did you check to make sure that item exists?

If you query for that item (use the [API Explorer](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO) if you need a quick way to do so what does the item XML response from Intuit look like?